# Best workflow for publication-quality figures with multiple subplots?

Tags: publications, graphics, formatting

What’s the best way to create full publication-quality (i.e. vector) figures from multiple subplots, from various sources? For example, I want to include a TIFF microscopy image and an EPS plot exported from Matlab in the same figure. A friend suggested PowerPoint, but it [no longer supports EPS plots](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Support-for-EPS-images-has-been-turned-off-in-Office-a069d664-4bcf-415e-a1b5-cbb0c334a840?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). Loading and exporting the full figures from Matlab is an option. I haven't used LaTeX – if this is suggested, what packages would be required?

My journal requires figures to be in EPS or TIFF format.

Comment: What software do you have available? Adobe Illustrator?

Comment: If you are making the image by hand, not programatically, then another application that could do the job is Inkscape. This isn't a matter of workflow, though. And don't learn LaTeX just for this task.

Comment: I don't have Illustrator, but I'll take a look at Inkscape!

Comment: Please strongly reconsider whether this really is a good approach for your situation. Unless your plot is using the same axes as your microscopy image, they probably should be separate plots and what you intend to do sounds like one of those difficult-to-read mash-up plots.

Comment: I would use Matlab, check for [subimages](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html), and [https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/display-multiple-images-in-the-same-figure.html](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/display-multiple-images-in-the-same-figure.html), and [(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884832/how-to-import-an-eps-file-and-insert-the-image-to-some-position-of-a-figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884832/how-to-import-an-eps-file-and-insert-the-image-to-some-position-of-a-figure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating figures with multiple subplots requires a lot of fine tuning that make programmatic approaches (like LaTeX, or R) tricky. It usually makes more sense to do this by hand, since the layout of subplots can change depending on personal preferences and revisions.

A few options:

- Inkscape is a good open source tool for making vector graphics, as mentioned
- Adobe Illustrator is a common, professional tool for vector graphics
- [Affinity Designer](https://affinity.serif.com/en-gb/designer/) is a cheaper professional alternative to Illustrator, and works very well with many different file formats, and I've found more intuitive than Illustrator